# ansible 2 \ include other yml doesn't work, though direct call is working

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have this in my all.yml
can't run tagger.yml (though when running tagger.yml directly it is working)

```
---
  - name: run couple of ymls
    hosts: all
    tasks:
      - include: "./tagger.yml"
        #- include: ./fluentd.yml
```

tagger.yml

```
---
  - name: tagger - build docker
    hosts: all  
    tags:
      - all
      - tagger
....
```

Error is

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "reason": "no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.\n\nThe error appears to have been in '.Build/tagger.yml': line 2, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n---\n  - name: tagger - build docker\n    ^ here\n\n\nThe error appears to have been in '.Build/tagger.yml': line 2, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n---\n  - name: tagger - build docker\n    ^ here\n"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ansible has two "levels", one is the playbook level, where you can supply plays, the other one is the task level, where you can supply tasks. The include works on both levels, but you won't be able to include new plays if you're already at the tasks level.

For example this is okay:

```
main.yml

---
- include: play1.yml
- include: play2.yml

play1.yml

----
- name: run couple of tasks on all hosts
  hosts: all
  tasks: [{debug: {msg: "Task1"}}]

play2.yml

----
- name: run some more tasks on some hosts
  hosts: some
  tasks: [{debug: {msg: "Task2"}}]
```

As here in the `main.yml` you are still at the playbook level, so you can include the files, which are playbooks themselves as well. This means that you can simply run `play1.yml` separately from `ansible-playbook` anytime as well.

But, once you are at the task level, you can only include files that only contain tasks:

```
main.yml

---
- name: run couple of ymls
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - include: "task1.yml"
    - include: "task2.yml"

task1.yml

---
- name: An actual command
  debug: { msg: "Task 1" }

task2.yml

---
- name: An other actual command
  debug: { msg: "Task 2" }
```

This is also okay, as both `task1.yml` and `task2.yml` files only contain tasks, and they are *not* full-fledged playbooks. Trying to run them separately with `ansible-playbook` won't work anymore, as they are only a bunch of tasks.

Note that in this example, if you'd include `play1.yml` instead of like `task1.yml`, then the playbook would fail, as you're already at the "tasks" level, from where you can't import any more playbooks.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer - tried that and now it is working!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `hosts` from your `tagger.yml` file:

```
---
  - name: tagger - build docker
    whatever task here 
    tags:
      - all
      - tagger
```

Hope that help you

Comment: thanks :) doesn't work...even removed the tags from tagger.yml

Comment: not tags but the `hosts` remove it and showed the result/error and configuration

Comment: right - I removed also the hosts. tried many things - I think it's related to the thing I can't have "tasks" section both at parent or child (or something..) still investigating